# NativeScript with redux... getting errors

Tags: redux, nativescript

so for 2 days been trying to get Redux working with NativeScript and angular 2 and no luck... all works fine in browser but not in NativeScript... and can't find a single example on the entire web for anyone using redux with NS... :/

this is the error

```
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/Lib.js:23:62
JS:     at NgModuleInjector.Object.defineProperty.get (AppModule.ngfactory.js:210:61)
JS:     at NgModuleInjector.AppModuleInjector.getInternal (AppModule.ngfactory.js:284:48)
JS:     at NgModuleInjector.get (/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7135:31)
JS:     at ElementInjector.get (/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9208:52)
JS:     at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3297:28)
JS:     at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3263:29)
JS:     at ReflectiveInjector_.get (/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3072:25)
JS:     at DebugAppView._View_LoginComponent_Host0.createInternal (LoginComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:16:189)
JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.create (/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9323:25)
JS: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./LoginComponent class LoginComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: thunkMiddleware is not defined
```

not very informative I know.
I would thing NativeScript guys would have a single example with redux but no such luck.

The only thing I can get working is just a redux store with a single reducer.
but as soon as I try to combineReducers or add middleware, it all explodes...

no idea why

all vanilla redux stuff:

```
    const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(<any>thunkMiddleware);
    const enhancers = compose(middlewareEnhancer);
    const createStoreWithEnhancers = enhancers(createStore);
    const reduxAppStore = createStoreWithEnhancers(reducerList);
    return reduxAppStore;
```

I welcome any help but at this point, without any stack trace info I can work with, I feel it's a lost cause...

regards

Sean

Answer (score 0):

Hey Sean I already replied to you in the issues - 
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2939

Lets move the discussion there.

Comment: thanks for replying, I will reply as well, but please understand that you provided an example of ngrx and not Redux...not the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

so tx to vakrilov the answer is simple.
managed to work-around it by adding

`global.process = { env: {} }`

in my `main.ts` just before all the imports.

now this works in NativeScript :)

`...
            const reducers = combineReducers(reducerList);
            const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(<any>thunkMiddleware);
            const enhancers = compose(middlewareEnhancer);
            const createStoreWithEnhancers = enhancers(createStore);
            const reduxAppStore = createStoreWithEnhancers(reducers);
            return reduxAppStore;`